# Export Gridview to ExcelSheet from an application in c# on IIS Server to a specific machine on the network

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, gridview, export-to-excel

I have hosted my application on the server.
The task is to Export Gridview to ExcelSheet from an application in c# on IIS Server to a specific machine on the network(Not on local machine of the user).
Here is the code that I have used

```
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
string renderedGridView = stringWrite.ToString();
File.WriteAllText(@"path of the server" + filename+ ".xls", renderedGridView);
Response.Write("<script>alert('File Successfully saved to server!')</script>");
```

This piece of code is working perfectly when I run it on my local machine.It creates the excel file at the specified location.But when I put the same code on my IIS server and the run it from the server,the file does not get exported anywhere.

Path of the server that I use is:

```
\\Machine IPaddress\machine name\Folder\SubFolder\filename.xls
```

I can access this location by using the above path in my run.
This path works well on my local machine.Do I need to change the path when I host my application on IIS server?If yes then what should be changed?

What should I do to make it work?Please help.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;



            response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
   response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+PathToServer +"ReportExport.xls");
   response.Write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC " + Convert.ToChar(34) + "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" + Convert.ToChar(34) + " " + Convert.ToChar(34) +
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" + Convert.ToChar(34) + ">" + "\n" +
        "<html xmlns=" + Convert.ToChar(34) + "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" + Convert.ToChar(34) + ">" + "\n" +
        "<head>"  + "\n"+
        "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>"  +"\n"+
        "</head><body>");


            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {


                sw.Write(StrHeader); // put strHeader as table string
                    using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
                        response.Write(sw.ToString());
                        response.Flush();
                        response.End(); 
                    }
                }
```